# XSLT namespace print in node

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't konw why in my output result i found the namespace in the node ... :

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.04" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.04 file://BE-FILE01/tverschu$/SR%20(Standards%20Release)/SR2013/ISO/Payments%20Clearing%20and%20settlement/SR2013_MX_Schemas_PaymentsClearingAndSettlement/pacs.008.001.04.xsd">
<FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
    <test xmlns:pacs="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.04">BBBBIE2D</test>
    <CdtTrfTxInf>
        <PmtId>
            <InstrId>BBBB/121109/-CBJ056/1</InstrId>
            <EndToEndId>CROPS/SX-25T/2012-10-13</EndToEndId>
            <TxId>AAAA/121109-CCT/EUR/443/1</TxId>
```

My XSLT File :

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:pacs="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.04"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="//pacs:GrpHdr[pacs:SttlmInf]">

 <test>
 <xsl:value-of select="pacs:InstgAgt/pacs:FinInstnId/pacs:BICFI[text()]" />
 </test>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Input File :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.04" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.008.001.04 file://BE-FILE01/tverschu$/SR%20(Standards%20Release)/SR2013/ISO/Payments%20Clearing%20and%20settlement/SR2013_MX_Schemas_PaymentsClearingAndSettlement/pacs.008.001.04.xsd">
    <FIToFICstmrCdtTrf>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>BBBB/121109-CBJO56</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2012-11-09T10:13:00</CreDtTm>
            <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
            <SttlmInf>
                <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
                <ClrSys>
                    <Prtry>CBJ</Prtry>
                </ClrSys>
            </SttlmInf>
            <InstgAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BICFI>BBBBIE2D</BICFI>
                </FinInstnId>
            </InstgAgt>
            <InstdAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <BICFI>CCCCIE2D</BICFI>
                </FinInstnId>
            </InstdAgt>
        </GrpHdr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a stylesheet based on the identity stylesheet. The default processing for nodes is to copy them to the output document. A namespace declaration is a node like any other; if you don't say to do something else with it, it gets copied. (It may also be copied/recreated automagically if you copy a node that needs that prefix to express its semantics.)

You can use the exclude-result-prefixes feature of XSLT to selectively suppress namespace declarations that are never referenced ... but be careful; if the prefix is used inside a string (eg in an XPath) you risk breaking your document by doing so.